# Windows service cannot read/watch from c:\windows\system32\foldername

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

I have a .net core 3.1 worker service running as a windows service. It is working fine for every other location but not able to watch files from this directory c:\windows\system32\xfolder(working when i debug from visual studio but gives error directory doesn't exist when accessed as a windows service).

**exception:System.ArgumentException: The directory name 'C:\Windows\System32\xfolder\' does not exist.**

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
                watcher.Path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\xfolder";  
                watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
               watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes |
                NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
                NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
                NotifyFilters.FileName |
                NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                NotifyFilters.Security |
                NotifyFilters.Size;
                watcher.Filter = "*.*";
                watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: Does you service has an access rights to this folder? Do you run it under the local system or specific user?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski service is running under local system, and how can i assign rights for local system.

Comment: @EduardoJiménez run your service with some user with required rights to the folder location.

Comment: I tried to run the app with administrator privileges but didn't work. As I was trying to search for some event logs, I changed to EventWatcher